# How to convert JSON with inline text styling to html text styling?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am trying to convert JSON from editorjs to html.

```
 {
         "type":"paragraph",
         "data":{
            "text":"This is a test of various inline styles - <b>bold</b> <i><b>bold italic </b>and just italic</i>"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"paragraph",
         "data":{
            "text":"<b>bold</b>"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"paragraph",
         "data":{
            "text":"<b><i>bold Italic</i></b>"
         }
      },
```

An example json from editorjs is above.

Right now, I an rendering the paragraph as a whole.

```
case "paragraph":
  return <Typography variant="subtitle1">{data.text}</Typography>;
```

If I write a function, should it evaluate character by character?

This is for a react app so looking for javascript solution. Also do not want to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Comment: ` <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data.text }}></div>`

Comment: The point is that you want to preserve the styles, right?  It's easy if you strip them.  I've got the strings parsed into DOM nodes using `DOMParser` and I can use plain JS methods to append them to the DOM tree but that doesn't feel right.  There's got to be a more react-y way...

Answer (score 1):

https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html is a good resource for this answer.

```
function createMarkup() {
  return {__html: 'First &middot; Second'};
}

function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;
}
```

Comment: Right above the code you copied from, it says in react documentation, using this is risky -setting HTML from code is risky because it’s easy to inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack. you can set HTML directly from React, but you have to type out dangerouslySetInnerHTML and pass an object with a __html key, to remind yourself that it’s dangerous.

Comment: Appreciate the answer though. upvoting but not accepting as the answer.